# Can't click next page table (onclick=proceed()) with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I've tried many ways to do this but I still can't get to the next page. I'm using Selenium on Python and the SafariDriver.

The Next Page table is as follows:

```
<div id="input_nav">
<table class="nav_entry" onclick="proceed();" align="right">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td align="right">Next Step:<br><div id="nav_title">Select Model/Chain</div></td>
    <td width="51" align="left"><img src="images/basic/next.png"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

I have tried

```
next_page = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='input_nav']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/img")
next_page.click()
# next_page.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) # also tried this
```

and

```
next_page = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='input_nav']/table")
```

and

```
next_page = browser.find_element(By.ID, "nav_title")
ed = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(browser)
ed.move_to_element(next_page).move_by_offset(1,1).click().perform()
```

and

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"nav_entry"))).find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='nav_title']").click()
```

but none of these work. They run but nothing happens on the page. Would anyone happen to know how to click the next page? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your URL to have a look.

Comment: Here's the [link](https://www.charmm-gui.org/?doc=input/membrane.bilayer&step=0) but you'd have to log in to the site to access it I'm afraid.

Comment: <table class="nav_entry" onclick="proceed();" align="right"> you might have to click on this element since it has an onclick method.

Comment: I tried that by copying the xpath to that exact line but clicking it doesn't get me to the next page. It only focuses on that element for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the SafariDriver. Clicking the element worked just fine with ChromeDriver.